# Get back to IO fiber/thread after running a future

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I have some cats IO operations, and Future among then. Simplified:

```
IO(getValue())
  .flatMap(v => IO.fromFuture(IO(blockingProcessValue(v)))(myBlockingPoolContextShift))
  .map(moreProcessing)
```

So I have some value in IO, then I need to do some blocking operation using a library that returns `Future`, and then I need to do some more processing on the value returned from `Future`

`Future` runs on a dedicated thread pool - so far so good. The problem is after `Future` is completed. `moreProcessing` runs on the same thread the `Future` was running on.

Is there a way to get back to the thread `getValue()` was running on?

Comment: Do you have reference to `ExectutionContext` or `ContextShift` on which `IO(getValue())` executed? If so  you can shift execution via : https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/api/cats/effect/ContextShift.html#shift:F[Unit]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have one. And the problem is there is no way to get it AFAIK :(

Comment: Can you execute then `map(moreProcessing)` on Future itself rather then on IO? So avoid this context switch? Or all next chain will be executed on blocking ec?

Comment: I can, but the point of using IO is not to use Futures, so it kind of isn't worth the effort at all.

Comment: No no I'm sorry, I mean not to get rid of IO completely, but to move `map` from IO to Future, like: ```IO(getValue())
  .flatMap(v => IO.fromFuture(IO(blockingProcessValue(v)))(myBlockingPoolContextShift).map(moreProcessing))```

Comment: Well, what's the difference? Still, it's executing `moreProcessing` on the same ExecutionContext as Future. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm sorry, my last comment was silly, apologize.

Comment: You should receive a **ContextShift** and a **Blocker**. That way you should be able to do something like `flatMap(v => Blocker.blockOn(IO.fromFuture(IO(blockingProcessing(v))))`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It doesn't work :( Unfortunately, after blocker, still next operations are running on the same thread pool the future was running on. Not on the same thread, but I guess it was Future that switched to another thread. Anyway, before blocker it was running on a thread from outside of the pool and after blocker it didn't return on this thread.

Comment: @amorfis Does this works? `.flatMap(v => blocker.blockOn(IO.fromFuture(IO(blockingProcessValue(v)(blocker.blockingContext))) *> cs.shift)`

Comment: But I don't have this CS. The one that IO runs in the beginning. Here is a snippet that shows the problem: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/amorfis/FYL2vjGtSOqaN9Tx23vpZA/21

Comment: @amorfis Don't do that, do not create a **ContextShift** from a blocking execution context; actually do not create a **ContextShift** ask for one. If you are using **IOApp** the runtime system will provide you with a **ContextShift** pass that one from the main down the call stack until your code, the same goes for the **Blocker**, create one in the main and pass it explicitly to your function.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't use IOApp and don't have access to CS.

But still, when **I want** to shift to another thread pool (for running Future), I should create CS, shouldn't I?

Comment: If you are not using **IOApp** you should do something similar to what it does, create an entry point, define everything you need there including your `cs` from the `global` EC or your custom EC and pass down the method calls. I hope this gives you an idea of how to design your code: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/vpU9lDU0TMa7dO80ByxKYw/7 let me know if that is enough for an answer or if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez. I'm sorry but I quite don't quite get it. What if I want to run my whole composed IO as .unsafeRunSync ? How do I pass CS then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230274/discussion-between-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez-and-amorfis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the discussion in the chat, the conclusion is that the only thing OP needs is to create a `ContextShift` in the application entry point using the appropriate *(compute)* **EC** and then pass it down to the class containing this method.

```scala
// Entry point

val computeEC = ???
val cs = IO.contextShift(computeEC)
val myClass = new MyClass(cs, ...)

// Inside the method on MyClass
IO(getValue())
  .flatMap(v => IO.fromFuture(IO(blockingProcessValue(v)))(myBlockingPoolContextShift))
  .flatTap(_ => cs.shift)
  .map(moreProcessing)
```

---

*This [**Scastie**](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/vpU9lDU0TMa7dO80ByxKYw/7) showed an approach using `Blocker` and other techniques common in the **Typelevel** ecosystem but were not really suitable for OP's use case; anyways I find it useful for future readers who may have a similar problem*.